# Allow ignore days or months in PHP dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have date field in my MySQL DB and three fields (yyyy-mm-dd) in my PHP form.
The user would set a complete date but can also set a "yyyy-mm" or "yyyy" date.
In MySQL everything is going right, if the user only set the year, it store "yyyy-00-00". So as there is no 00 day in a month and no 00 month in a year, it acts like a "NULL" day or month.

But, when i want to display de date back to the user, using th date_format PHP function, if the date is "2012-00-00", it display "2011-12-30".

How can I easily (not using have_day and have_month columns in the db) handled this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to display to the user?

Comment: The full date if complete, the year only if the date is like "yyyy-00-00" and the year and month if the date is like "yyyy-mm-00".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is unusual. You cannot use DATE class to format dates. Try treating date as literal string.

```
if (strstr($date_returned,'-00-00'))
{
    echo  str_replace('-00-00','',$date_returned).'-00-00';
}
```

Comment: Great idea!
What do you think of something like this?
    switch(strpos($date, '00')){
        catch 0:
            // error
            break;
        case 5:
            // year only
            break;
        case 8:
            // year and month only
            break;
        default:
            // complete date
            break;
    }

Comment: I have to say this, if you have to implement solution like your comment, its time to change the approach to find a better solution. What you are doing is not natural and its in most cases its a good idea to rethink the code.

Comment: Why is that a bad solution and how to do it another way?